# User drawn line disappear but the functionality behind it does not

Tags: java, android

I am creating a puzzle game [hashi](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hashiwokakero), basically the purpose of the game is to solve a puzzle using connection (Bridges) and Nodes(Islands).
To solve the puzzle, the user has to connect the same amount of bridges to a corresponding nodes weight.

The user is allowed to join the islands using 2 bridges from one island, but after s/he tries to connect the 3 bridges from the same node the connection should disappear and the user should be allowed to create a new one from that node.

**Problem:**
The user can draw 2 bridges from the same node but once he tries to do a third one the connection disappear JUST VISUALLY meaning the nodes are still connected and then the user cannot draw a bridge again.

[image: *]

And in here the bridges are just deleted visually.

[image: *]

I tried to debug it, but unfortunately I cannot seem to figure out where the problem is.

Here is the code to my problem.

```
public class BoardCreation {
  // This class member is used for random initialization purposes.
  static private final Random random = new Random();

  // The difficulty levels.
  private static final int EASY = 0;
  static public final int MEDIUM = 1;
  static public final int HARD = 2;

  static public final int EMPTY = 0;

  private static int ConnectionFingerprint(BoardElement start, BoardElement end) {
    int x = start.row * 100 + start.col;
    int y = end.row * 100 + end.col;
    // Swap to get always the same fingerprint independent whether we are called
    // start-end or end-start
    if (x > y ) {
      int temp = x;
      x = y;
      y = temp;
    }
    Log.d("", String.format("%d %d" , x ,y));
    return x ^ y;
  }

  public class State {
    // The elements of the board are stored in this array.
    // A value defined by "EMPTY" means that its not set yet.
    public BoardElement [][] board_elements = null;

    public int [][] cell_occupied = null;

    // The width of the board. We only assume squared boards.
    public int board_width=0;


    public State(int width) {
      board_width = width;
      board_elements = new BoardElement[width][width];
      cell_occupied = new int[width][width];
    }

    public State CloneWithoutConnections() {
      State newstate = new State(board_width);
      if (board_elements != null) {
    newstate.board_elements = new BoardElement[board_elements.length][board_elements.length];
    for (int i = 0; i < board_elements.length; ++i) {
      for (int j = 0; j < board_elements.length; ++j) {
        if (board_elements[i][j] == null)
              continue;
        newstate.board_elements[i][j] = board_elements[i][j].clone();
      }
    }
      }
      if (cell_occupied != null) {
          assert board_elements != null;
          newstate.cell_occupied = new int[board_elements.length][board_elements.length];
    for (int i = 0; i < board_elements.length; ++i) {
        System.arraycopy(cell_occupied[i], 0, newstate.cell_occupied[i], 0, board_elements.length);
    }
      }
      return newstate;
    }

    public void AddToBridgeCache(BoardElement first, BoardElement second) {
      if (first == null || second == null) { return; }
      final int fingerprint = ConnectionFingerprint(first, second);
      Log.d(getClass().getName(),
          String.format("Fingerprint of this bridge %d", fingerprint));
      // mark the end points as occupied.
      cell_occupied[first.row][first.col] = fingerprint;
      cell_occupied[second.row][second.col] = fingerprint;

      int dcol = second.col - first.col;
      int drow = second.row - first.row;

      if (first.row == second.row) {
    for (int i = (int) (first.col + Math.signum(dcol)); i != second.col; i += Math.signum(dcol)) {
      cell_occupied[first.row][i] = fingerprint;
        String.format("deleting bridge");
    }
      } else {
    assert first.col == second.col;
    for (int i = (int) (first.row + Math.signum(drow)); i != second.row; i+= Math.signum(drow)) {
      cell_occupied[i][first.col] = fingerprint;
        String.format("deleting bridge", fingerprint);

    }
      }
    }
  } // end of state
}
```

Comment: I can't follow the code completely (the uneven indenting doesn't help) but you seem to be setting `cell_occupied[??][??] = fingerprint` (for various indices) at various points, which I assume is you "recording" the bridges, but I can't see anywhere where you set this back to an empty/no-bridge value.

Comment: @TripeHound I am trying to delete the bridge using this i am trying to print "deleteing bridge" for debuging but i can't see it in the logs`if (first.row == second.row) {
    for (int i = (int) (first.col + Math.signum(dcol)); i != second.col; i += Math.signum(dcol)) {
      cell_occupied[first.row][i] = fingerprint;
        String.format("deleting bridge");
    }`

Comment: You're not actually _printing_ or logging those messages in the code above: you're just formatting a string and throwing it away. But the main question is: is setting that cell to `fingerprint` the right way of deleting the bridge? Should it not be set to `null` or zero or something? (I don't know... I've not followed the code sufficiently but you don't appear to be setting those cells to anything _other_ than `fingerprint`, which doesn't seem right).